# What is a good C++ API Design for HW registers?

Tags: c++, api

I am designing an API for a driver that manipulates HW. I have done the following:

```
namespace HWRegister
{
    //private:
    namespace Data
    {
        //accessible only within this namespace

        //Represents one of the four HW blocks.
        enum EHWUnit
        {
            Block0,
            Block1,
            Block2,
            Block3
        };

        enum EHWSet
        {
            Rx0,
            Rx1,
            Rx2,
            Rx3,
            Tx0,
            Tx1,
            Tx2,
            Tx3
        };
    }

    using namespace Data;

    //Returns Error Code
    int32_t enableHWUnit( const EHWUnit aHWNumber, const EHWSet aHWSet );
    //Returns Error Code.
    int32_t disableHWUnit( const EHWUnit aHWNumber );
```

I would like to get peoples opinion on this. I am wondering if those enums are a good idea, I declare them here and therefore people who use my API are forced to use them, will this cause more problems for the callers of my API? Can I improve this API somehow? I will add more documentation into the API when I am sure it is looking good.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55085/feedback-on-my-api-design?noredirect=1#comment96428_55085

Comment: @user1876942 Quite weird. I also thought it is more appropriate for code review.

Comment: Ahem, not exactly working code is it?  Code Review wants working code to review.

Comment: Notice that user C++ code will change the hardware registers (because the C++ compiler emits assembler code working with registers). So unless your registers are so specialized that the compiler don't know about them, I believe your question might not make any sense.

Comment: If your goal is to make these enums accessible only to one class, you should use **nested enums** (colloquially called class member enums). See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5030785/) for an example.

Comment: If there is a set of constant values used by the hardware, it is the usual practice to explicitly assign those same values to the enums that represent them (so that the helper functions can obtain the underlying values easily with a cast).

Comment: It is also customary to give meaningful names to the enums.

Answer (score 1):

Enums are always good to use, since they make code easier to understand.

But, you have several problems there :

- if your code snipet is in a header, then the namespace must have a name
- I would use strongly typed enum `enum class`, instead of just `enum`
- your enum values are not descriptive enough, and sounds very generic. You may want to give better names, instead of just for example `Tx1`. With strongly typed enums, this is not an issue
- not a big deal, but your functions return an error code. An exception may be more approriate
- Why not create a class, which initializes your HW in constructor, and disable in destructor? Your API looks more like C

Comment: The namespace HW register uses the anonymous namespace as I thought this is the way to make it "private"  So, those enums are private.

I will look into exceptions over error codes. Which are better etc.. 

My SW does not initialize the HW, hence why I used a namespace, I can just call it like is is static.

The rest I agree with and will change.

Comment: @user1876942 Don't put an anonymous namespace in a header, ever.

Comment: Where should I put them?  It seems like the recommended thing:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154469/unnamed-anonymous-namespaces-vs-static-functions

Comment: @user1876942 "Unnamed namespaces still have the advantage of allowing you to define translation-unit-local types." (from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/154482/476681)). So, add a name to that namespace

Comment: I read from that link that unnamed namespaces are good, yet you're saying add a name.  After that it is no longer unnamed?  Can you give an example?

Comment: @user1876942 `namespace HWRegister` is a namespace with name. Unnamed namespaces are good for source files, but not for headers.

Comment: So, the namespace, inside the namespace HWRegister needs a name too?  That unnamed namespace only holds the enums.

Comment: @user1876942 Yes, it needs a name. Doesn't matter what it holds, it is an unnamed namespace.

Comment: I made those changes, but now I guess that namespace Data is useless.  Why not just put the enums in the namespace HWRegister?

Comment: @user1876942 Either that, and change enums into `enum class`, or keep it.

Comment: Don't rely on unnamed namespaces for visibility control. Instead, put types (nested) inside a C++ class and use the visibility specifiers `public`, `protected`, `private` and `friend`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Enums are a good idea
2. If you'll provide this code via dll (good idea for me), I'd recommend not to change them into `enum class` and not no throw the exception, because these are C++ only features, and users will be not able to use your dll in C# for example
3. If these enums will be used as a real register address (or offset) it would be better to initialize each member of enum with a particular value (even if they are 0, 1, 2, etc.) in hex fromat (it's agreed notation in HW - driver - user program bundle)

   ```
   enum EHWSet
   {
       Rx0 = 0x00,
       Rx1 = 0x01,
       Rx2 = 0x02,
       Rx3 = 0x03,
       Tx0 = 0x04,
       Tx1 = 0x05,
       Tx2 = 0x06,
       Tx3 = 0x07
   };
   ```
4. Exclude `using namespace` from header. It's a very very very bad idea